# Why this code doesn't give the output after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't give the required output.I can't figure out why document.getElementById("demo")=text; isn't working here. Although  x=document.getElementById("numb").value; is working correctly. I checked this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Please input a number between 0 and 4:</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function check() {
         var text,x;
       x=document.getElementById("numb").value;
       switch(x){
        case 0:
        text= "This is Zero";
            break;
        case 1:
         text = "This is One";
            break;
        case 2:
         text= "This is Two";
            break;
        case 3:
          text= "This is Three";
            break;
        case 4:
           text= "This is Four";
            break;
       default:
          text="Wrong Input";
    }    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;//this gives nothing. 
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your value of document.getElementById("numb").value returns the character entered in the input.

You need to switch cases for 
Case "0":
Case "1":
Case "2":
etc

Answer (score 2):

The value you are getting here `x=document.getElementById("numb").value` is  string not integer

Either you need to check as string

```js
function check() {
         var text,x;
       x=document.getElementById("numb").value;
       console.log(x);
       switch(x){
        case '0':
        text= "This is Zero";
            break;
        case '1':
         text = "This is One";
            break;
        case '2':
         text= "This is Two";
            break;
        case '3':
          text= "This is Three";
            break;
        case '4':
           text= "This is Four";
            break;
       default:
          text="Wrong Input";
    }    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;//this gives nothing. 
    }
```

```html
<p>Please input a number between 0 and 4:</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Or parse value of `x` as integer

```js
function check() {
         var text,x;
       x=document.getElementById("numb").value;
       x = parseInt(x);
       switch(x){
        case 0:
        text= "This is Zero";
            break;
        case 1:
         text = "This is One";
            break;
        case 2:
         text= "This is Two";
            break;
        case 3:
          text= "This is Three";
            break;
        case 4:
           text= "This is Four";
            break;
       default:
          text="Wrong Input";
    }    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;//this gives nothing. 
    }
```

```html
<p>Please input a number between 0 and 4:</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=parseInt(document.getElementById("numb").value);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of x to Integer.

Like this `x = parseInt(x)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Please input a number between 0 and 4:</p>
    <input id="numb">
    <button type="button" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function check() {
         var text,x;
       x=document.getElementById("numb").value;
       alert(x);
       x = parseInt(x);
       switch(x){
        case 0:
        text= "This is Zero";
            break;
        case 1:
         text = "This is One";
            break;
        case 2:
         text= "This is Two";
            break;
        case 3:
          text= "This is Three";
            break;
        case 4:
           text= "This is Four";
            break;
       default:
          text="Wrong Input";
    }    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;//this gives nothing. 
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I removed it. It was initially for not explaining what the issue was.